# Separating References in an Array

Tags: php, arrays, reference

I have an array that looks like this in `var_dump`:

```
array(2) {
  ["foo"] => &array(2) {
    ["hello"] => string(5) "world"
    ["number"] => float(21)
  }
  ["bar"] => &array(2) {
    ["hello"] => string(5) "world"
    ["number"] => float(21)
  }
}
```

In this array, both the `foo` and `bar` keys in the array are referencing the same array, but I need them to be separate arrays.

Is there a way to cut all the references in an array?

Note: The actual array my code generates is *much* more complex than this, with many layers and references. I would prefer to not have to brute-force through the array to cut the references, but any solution is better than none.

I tried to change the way my code generates it to fix the references, but because of the algorithm I'm using, it won't work. The only way I can fix it is to rewrite my whole generator to not use the references to begin with. (I would really like to not have to do that)

Comment: Can you `slice()` a shallow copy at the correct times and assign to them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't think of an easy way, so this is my rather crude solution; simply copy all the things:

```
function clone_array(array $arr)
{
    $res = [];
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
        $res[$k] = is_array($v) ? clone_array($v) : $v;
    }
    return $res;
}
```

Comment: Darn, that was the kind of solution I was expecting but I was really hoping there would be a better way (internal/really fast). =(